# What does 如此 mean in 表示显然如此或确实?

Tags: meaning-in-context, adverbs

In the following sentence that explains the usage of 明明:

> 表示显然**如此**或确实，下文的意思往往转折。

The meaning would be something like the following:

> It shows obviousness **or such**, or certainity. After the word usually comes the turnover's meaning.

But I don't understand why it needs 如此 here, and what it works for.

In my understanding, 如此 is used to emphasize an adjective or adverb, and put before the adjective or adverb to mean "so" (equal to 很). But in this case it is put after the word.

Does it have any difference on the meaning with or without 如此? What nuances does it carry?

Comment: A word often has several meanings.

Comment: 如此 precedes adjectives (as adverb), follows verbs， nouns, phrases，e.g.
这样：如此勇敢 | 理当如此 | 事已如此，后悔也是枉然, 我早就知道如此，accordingly in 表示显然如此或确实     如此 applies to the phrase  表示显然, while 或确实 can be understood as abbreviation of 或表示确实如此 avoiding repetition of 表示...如此

Answer (score 1):

Literally, 如 means "like" and 此 means "this".

如此 as a verb means 是这样, (something) to be the case.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, 如此 has to be there and can't be dropped.

表示显然如此 means **denote obviously like that/this**.

Comment: Thanks but why does it have to be combined, and how can I know if what word should be combined or not...?

Answer (score 1):

This is just dictionary language, short and direct, not prose. People I asked had no problem with removing 如此, which, as Jason said is quite literally 'like this', 显然如此 = clearly / evidently / obviously so

‘明明’表示显然如此或确实，下文的意思往往转折。
‘明明’表示显然———或确实，下文的意思往往转折。

You could expand the dictionary speak to:

‘明明’表示一件事情、一个情况是显然的或者确实的，在其后的正文通常出现转折。

你明明就知道什么。说话！
You obviously know something. Tell me!